# How to unlock only specific cells from write protected worksheet using excel javascript API

Tags: excel, office-js

I am using office 365 and Excel online (Build 16.0.9403.1875).

and I am creating Microsoft Excel online [Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview), using [Excel javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts).

I have a requirement like write protection for entire sheet except few cells (Range).

So, I referred [Format protection API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/formatprotection), but while debugging, the ‘locked’ property is of no effect in action.

I referred, stack over flow too with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463578/how-to-lock-only-dedicated-cells-via-excel-javascript-api)

And [others](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ignite-ui-for-javascript/109693/how-to-lock-unlock-excel-cells) too

As, I have already tried with the suggestion given by above forum links.

I just expecting reply by working snippet of code.

My code samples are below

```
  Excel.run(function (ctx) {
  //Worksheet
  var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");

  //Entire Range
  var entireRange = sheet.getRange();
  entireRange.format.protection.locked = false;  

  //Specific Range
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B5");  

  return ctx.sync()
    .then(() => {
      //Set specific range "locked" status to true.
      range.format.protection.locked = true;
    })
    .then(ctx.sync)
    .then(() => {
      //Protect Entire sheet
      sheet.protection.protect({
        allowInsertRows: false,
        allowDeleteRows: false
      });
    });
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

Thanks.