# How to lock a range in excel via office add-in

Tags: office-js

I'm developing an excel add-in using js.
I want to lock some cells or rows or cols, while other cells can still be edited.
I haven't found a document about it.

I tried the following code but the range is not locked.

```js
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const range = sheet.getRange("B2:E5");
    range.format.protection.locked = true;

    await context.sync();
});
```

I found the solution:

```js
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var wholerange = sheet.getRange();
    wholerange.format.protection.locked = false;

    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D5");
    range.format.protection.locked = true;

    sheet.protection.protect({ allowInsertRows: true });
    await context.sync();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Range.format.protection property. See for example [Range.format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeformat?view=office-js) and [FormatProjection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.formatprotection?view=office-js).

**UPDATE:**
Locking ranges works in conjunction with Worksheet protection. The locking/unlocking of ranges has no effect until the worksheet is protected. See [WorksheetProtection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetprotection?view=office-js).

Also, the logic of range locking is the same as when an end-user locks ranges in the Excel UI: All cells will be locked by default when the worksheet is protected. So before you protect the worksheet, you *UN*lock the cells that should not be locked. Please work with locking and protection as an end-user until you are familiar with how it works and what the options are. For example, see this page [Lock cells Excel](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/lock-cells-excel).

Comment: The document is too simple, I still don't know how to realize it. I think it's the "excel.formatprotection.lock" api that controls the locking but I don't know how to bind it with a range.

Comment: I've added an snippet in my question but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, refer to [How to lock only dedicated cells via Excel JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463578/how-to-lock-only-dedicated-cells-via-excel-javascript-api/45466872#45466872)

```js
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var wholerange = sheet.getRange();
    wholerange.format.protection.locked = false;

    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D5");
    range.format.protection.locked = true;

    sheet.protection.protect({ allowInsertRows: true });
    await context.sync();
});
```