# How to set selectionMode to Unlocked? Excel add-in, Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I have a small excel add-in, written in office.js and using Visual Studio 2019.  Whatever I do, I can't get the add-in to protect the worksheet and allow the user to only select unlocked cells.

I've googled till my eyes bleed, best example for use is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463578/how-to-lock-only-dedicated-cells-via-excel-javascript-api/45466872#45466872).  This contains many options, but not the one I want!

Microsoft documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetprotectionoptions?view=excel-js-preview).

```
function ProtectSheet() {
     Excel.run(function (context) {
          var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
          sheet.protection.protect(); //works fine, obviously doesn't achieve what I want

          //here's the formats I've tried:
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode: "Unlocked" });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode: unlocked });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode: Excel.ProtectionSelectionMode "Unlocked" });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode: Excel.ProtectionSelectionMode unlocked });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode?: "Unlocked" });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode?: unlocked });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode?: Excel.ProtectionSelectionMode "Unlocked" });
          sheet.protection.protect({ SelectionMode?: Excel.ProtectionSelectionMode unlocked });

// all of the rest just compile to sheet.protection.protect() when viewing in the debugger;

          return context.sync();
     })
}
```

The sheet is protected, but the option to select only unused cells is not set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like a probable bug. Please raise this issue at the GitHub repo for the Office JavaScript library: [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set Unlock mode like below:

```
sheet.protection.protect("Unlocked");
```